# Model for how the shifting of industries affect job creation

Tags: macroeconomics, model

I am working on my Master's thesis (International Relations) and I want to argue, backed with data, that when an industry gets bigger in terms of production, efficiency, in detriment of another industry, it will eventually lead to the creation of new jobs.

Thing is, I am not an economics person, not by far. I can understand some of it but I can't model it myself. Would any of you have any idea for where to point me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an economics model of endogenous job creation across different industries in "Acemoglu, D., & Restrepo, P. (2018). The race between man and machine: Implications of technology for growth, factor shares, and employment. AER". However this is really the frontier of the literature and I doubt this model might be a little too advanced for non-econ master students.

For empirical work you can consult "Autor, D., Salomons, A., & Seegmiller, B. (2021). New Frontiers: The Origins and Content of New Work, 1940–2018. NBER." where basically you can find most relevant recent econ papers there.